# olingo-odata4-js project setup

Tags: installation, odata, olingo

I'm trying to follow the directions to setup olingo-odata4-js on a windows 8 machine.
http://olingo.apache.org/doc/javascript/project-setup.html

First Problem

> *After installing the main modules navigate into the folder /grunt- config/browserify_transforms/stripheader and call again npm install*

But there is no such directory anywhere in the cloned repo.

Second Problem

When I open up the solution in Visual Studio, the gnuget package manager asked to restore the packages. However, the following error occurs: "unable to find version 6.0.0-beta1 of package Microsoft.Odata.Service"

Anyone successfully go through the setup? Everything looks clean and well written. I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a bit long story about the missing Microsoft.OData.Service 6.x, it does exist but is not officially released to public. unlike Its previous version that is for odata V3 protocol, 6.x library is for odata V4 protocol, since Microsoft OData team decided to move away from WCF Data service, and instead wanted to recommend RESTier for OData V4, so 6.x's service dll was not released.

that is why Apache Olingo doesn't make it public either. but if you need, we can provide private bits to you for running olingo-js tests (as a temp solution).

Comment: Thank you for the information. If you would provide the .dll in some way i'd like to run the test examples. Is it not possible to put it as a link and a note on your project page letting people know about the issue?

Comment: Hi Watson, do you have an email for receiving it ? we ever considered removing this dependence, so didn't give add more information about it on the website.

Comment: by the way, odatajs is an open source project, it welcomes everyone's contribution, if someone wants to help replacing the old service dll service with the new https://github.com/OData/RESTier , we will be happy to see that.

Comment: You may send it to my personal gmail account at Kyle.l.Watson@gmail.com